# ¿Como llamar una CLASE desde otra CLASE?

Tags: java, android

A través de Android Studio estoy tratando de hacer una APP para mi celular, tengo una duda:

Para llamar una activity desde una clase, yo hago lo siguiente, no se si es lo mejor pero me funciona.

```
    Intent llamando_activity = new Intent(coordenadas.this, activity_principal.class);
    startActivity(llamando_activity);
```

**¿Como hago para llamar una clase desde otra clase?**

Mas exactamente tengo un clase llamada coordenadas y otra llamada cálculos,

¿Como hago para llamar la clase cálculos desde la clase coordenadas?

Gracias

Comment: Con clases te refieres a *actividades* o clases de java??? Es que si no llamas a las cosas por su nombre, es muy difícil ayudarte. Intenta no mezclar términos cuando explicas un problema. Si lo que necesitas es llamar a una clase normal, tan solo instánciala `MiClase miClase = new MiClase();`, si es otra activity... no deberías necesitar llamar a código de una `activity` desde otra, intenta buscar una solución alternativa para no andar pasando una `activity`, puesto que es mala práctica y suele provocar la mayoría de los leakings de memoria!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que agregas es para iniciar específicamente una activity dentro de tu aplicación:

```
   Intent llamando_activity = new Intent(coordenadas.this, activity_principal.class);
    startActivity(llamando_activity);
```

Pero si lo que quieres es llamar desde tu clase otra clase, debes instanciar la clase:

```
  Calculos miclase = new Calculos();
```

incluso al instanciar puedes llamar alguno de los métodos de la clase que instancias:

```
Calculos miclase = new Calculos();
miclase.metodo();
```